# Eager Loading Outside Active Record

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a collection non Active Record model that each have a few foreign keys. I'd like to eager load in the associations but I'm struggling with the approach. The code looks something like this:

Model:

```
class Tuple
  attr_accessor :widget_id
  attr_accessor :woogle_id

  def self.all
    # returns a bunch of tuples with ids
  end

  def widget
    @widget ||= Widget.find(widget_id)
  end

  def woogle
    @woogle ||= Woogle.find(woogle_id)
  end
end
```

View:

```
- Tuple.all.each do |tuple| 
  = render tuple.widget
  = render tuple.woogle
```

Any thoughts on how to eager load outside active record and avoid N+1 queries in this case?

Comment: What are you using in lieu of ActiveRecord? How are your records stored?

Comment: @gg_s The associated records are backed by ActiveRecord (only the Tuple is not backed by Active Record)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code should work for you, although it would be nice if there were a cleaner way to set the `@woogle` and `@widget` instance variables:

```
def self.all
  # get a bunch of tuples with ids
  all_tuples = some_logic
  widgets = Widget.where(id: all_tuples.map(&:widget_id)).inject({}){|m, w| m[w.id] = w; m}
  woogles = Woogle.where(id: all_tuples.map(&:woogle_id)).inject({}){|m, w| m[w.id] = w; m}
  all_tuples.each do |t|
    t.instance_variable_set :@widget, widgets[t.widget_id]
    t.instance_variable_set :@woogle, woogles[t.woogle_id]
  end
end
```

Note that if any Widget or Woogle associations for the Tuples are identical, only one instance of that association is actually eager-loaded and shared by the associated Tuples